# Generate Web Service Client from WSDL

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, jax-ws, webclient

I'm trying to generate a web client from a wsdl, but when I run maven Install I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin:1.4:wsdl2java (default) on project ClienteCreditCheck: Error
generating Java code from WSDL. Error running Axis: WSDLException (at
/definitions/types/xsd:schema):
 faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema.
```

Comment: Probably you are not put in the same directory all the custom xsd file referenced by the wsdl. Please add at least the complete header of the wsdl, it would make the question more clear.

Comment: Consider using [JAX-WS Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/) instead. The Axis one has not been maintained.